# ANGULAR WAY for accessing an element reference from both parent and sibling component - ERROR TypeError: undefined

Tags: angular, angular-components

This is should be easy but I don't seem to figure it out... I simply need to be able to reference an element from parent and sibling components... even using `@ViewChild` and `@ViewChildren` and of course `ngAfterViewInit`, I still get this `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`

QueryBoxComponent (Child 1)

```
<input
  type="text"
  (keyup)="onKeyup()"
  #queryInput
  placeholder="title, name, place or event"
  autocomplete="off"
  class="TAl xip6 inlf f120 b"
  required
  style="width: 100%;"
/>
```

QueryResetComponent (Child 2)

```
<span
  (click)="onClick()"
>
  {{queryInput.value}}</span>
```

ParentComponent

```
<query-box
                    [ngClass]="{
                      ns: isSearching
                    }"
                    (keyupEvent)="queryFilter(queryInput.value)"
                  ></query-box>
                  <query-reset
                    *ngIf="isSearching"
                    (clickEvent)="queryReset()"
                  ></query-reset>
```

Comment: NB: I already tried @ViewChild(QueryBoxComponent, {static: false}) queryBoxComponent: QueryBoxComponent; in the ParentComponent.ts file, then used (keyupEvent)="queryFilter(queryBoxComponent.queryInput.nativeElement.value)" in the ParentComponent.html and it still fails with similar error: undefined.

Comment: Using Angular Version 12

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to access `nativeElement` to extract it's value. Work with angular Forms Api instead. You can use [template driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms#building-a-template-driven-form) or [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms).

For your example you could set a `FormGroup` in the parent component and pass the value to the child components.

```
// ParentComponent.ts

import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...

export class ParentComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      search: this.fb.control('', Validators.required)
    })
  }

  queryReset() {
    this.form.get('search').reset();
  }
}

// ParentComponent.html

<query-box
  [ngClass]="{
    ns: isSearching
   }"
  [formGroup]="form"
></query-box>
<query-reset
 *ngIf="isSearching"
  (clickEvent)="queryReset()"
></query-reset>


// QueryBoxComponent.ts

...

@Input() formGroup: FormGroup;

...


// QueryBoxComponent.html

<form [formGroup]="formGroup">

<input
  type="text"
  formControlName="search"
  placeholder="title, name, place or event"
  autocomplete="off"
  class="TAl xip6 inlf f120 b"
  style="width: 100%;"
/>

</form>
```

With template driven forms you would use `ngModel` in the `QueryBoxComponent` to store value of the input field and then you could access it also with `@ViewChild` from parent component.

```
//adding value prop in the QueryBoxComponent.ts

public value: string = ''

//and binding it in the template

<input
  type="text"
  [(ngModel)]="value"
  placeholder="title, name, place or event"
  autocomplete="off"
  class="TAl xip6 inlf f120 b"
  required
  style="width: 100%;"
/>
```